# Android ScrollView Intercepts Clicks, should not do that

Tags: android, click, scrollview, touch-event

I have a view with an onClickListener inside of a scrollview. The view should react on clicks, but the scrollview interpretes almost all touches as ACTION_MOVE and intercepts the touch events, so i cannot click the view.

I have modified my scrollview as follows (because it is in a viewpager and needs to disable scrolling the viewpager)

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {
    if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(p_event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {
    if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && getParent() != null) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(p_event);
}
```

How can I change the sensitivity of the ScrollView to not register the tiniest movements as ACTION_MOVE and pass the touch events to its children?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it!
The first part is not necessary, if you modify the code as follows it works fine:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {
    /*if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return true;
    }*/
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(p_event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {
    if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && getParent() != null) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(p_event);
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks, but it's a compromise for me. I have 10 children inside my ScrollView, and with this I have to set the same click handler onto all of them. Ideally, I'd like my ScrollViews parent (or even the ScrollView itself) to respond to a click, but I can't get it to work for either of those cases. Either the scroll functionality will work, or the click functionality will work, but never both at the same time.